# How to read the parameters passed in react native cli commands programmatically?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, react-native-cli

How to read the variant value passed in react native cli command npx react-native **run-android --variant=release** programmatically?

Comment: I have trouble understanding your question. What exactly are you trying to achieve? What do you mean by "read"?

Comment: Sorry for posting incomplete question. 


I have two flavors of react native app:
1. “salesbuild”: “react-native run-android — variant=salesDebug”,
2. “marketingbuild”: “react-native run-android — variant=marketingDebug.

I need to obtain the variant value passed in cli when running the above commands, inside babel.config.js file in order to apply different plugins on different flavors of the app.